# what is difference between transaction and statement in database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-administration

I am reading a book called "PostgreSQL Administration cookbook 9.5-9.6 edition". And in this book on page-20 author tells if a user connecting to a PostgreSQL Cluster than he defines the connection as -
`"Once you've connected, each connection can have one active transaction at a time and one fully active statement at any time."`

I know that a execution of SQL command in database is called transaction but I doesn't fully understand meaning of **statement** in this context. I want to know what **statement** means here and how this is different from **transaction** in database.

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html)?

Comment: "execution of SQL command in database is called transaction" this is incorrect. A transaction something that wraps a set of statements. If something goes bad in the transaction, all change is rolled back. This allows you to run a bunch of statements *atomically*.

Comment: Transactions and statements are completely different concepts. A statement is the single line you execute. Without transactions, every modification is permanent. If you want to undo changes, you execute one or more statement inside a transaction and either commit all changes at once (making them permanent) or discard them all at once.

Comment: A transaction isn't just a batch of statements either. If you type 2 INSERTs and 5 DELETEs in a single string and execute that, every change will be permanent. You have to wrap all of these in a transaction if you want to roll them back

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so than `INSERT INTO table(name, age) VALUES('mark', 23);` is 
a statement and `BEGIN; INSERT INTO table(name, age) VALUES('mark', 23); COMMIT;` is a transaction right?

Comment: With autocommit they both are transactions. See [BEGIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html): *By default (without BEGIN), PostgreSQL executes transactions in “autocommit” mode, that is, each statement is executed in its own transaction and a commit is implicitly performed at the end of the statement (if execution was successful, otherwise a rollback is done).*.  A statement is the action you want the database to do, a transaction is how the database processes those actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *statement* is easily explained. It is an SQL statement that you send to the server (Something like `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `CREATE TABLE` and so on). There can only be one statement running in a database session at any given time, and you have to wait for the result of the previous statement before you can send the next one. (This is not 100% true: there is *pipeline mode*, in which you can send several statements to the server without waiting for the first ones to complete, but these statements are still executed one after the other. It is just a way to reduce the impact of network latency.)

A *transaction* is one or more SQL statements bundled together in a way to make the execution of the statements appear atomic: either all statements succeed or all fail, and the effects of any statement in the transaction only becomes visible to the outside when the transaction has been committed (completed successfully). By default, PostgreSQL runs each statement in its own transaction, but you can explicitly start a transaction with `START TRANSACTION` or `BEGIN`, which can span multiple statements.